Kogito + Quarkus (3.8.4)
Does anyone have a pom example that allows me to use Quarkus (3.8.4) with the latest version of Kogito, I tried to adapt the one proposed in the examples, but it doesn't work correctly for me.
For example try -> https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/main/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-saga-quarkus
Thanks for your help ...

Kogito hasn't finished the migration to quarkus 3 yet. So you cannot use Quarkus 3 at all yet.

Can you please describe why it doesn't work for you?

The problem was mine, I didn't understand the versions, in short it's the same thing that Snowe comments
